# javascript syntax error explaination

Tags: javascript

Help. I'm uncertain about about this error. It looks correct and the session attribute is not null.
I am getting a token error on the following:

*Syntax error on token "<", delete this token 
a cannot be resolved to a type
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
style cannot be resolved to a variabl*

```
    <%if (session.getAttribute("home").toString().equals("canada")) {
        <a href="homecanada.jsp" style="font-size:3px;">
            <img src="images/image.jpg" width="232" height="71" alt="alt text" class="logo"  />
        </a>
    <%}else{%>}
        <a href="homeusa.jsp" style="font-size:3px;">
            <img src="images/image.jpg" width="232" height="71" alt="alt text" class="logo"  />
        </a>
    <%}%>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `%>` after the first line ..... that's a typo !

Comment: And I guess `<%}else{%>}` is not right also. Maybe it should be `<%}else{%>` ?

Comment: OMG! Thank you thank you thank you! Thank you adeno and Andre and durbnpoisn.

Answer (score 0):

If looks like you have an extra bracket and a close tag:

```
   <%if (session.getAttribute("home").toString().equals("canada")) {%>
        <a href="homecanada.jsp" style="font-size:3px;">
            <img src="images/image.jpg" width="232" height="71" alt="alt text" class="logo"  />
        </a>
    <%}else{%>
        <a href="homeusa.jsp" style="font-size:3px;">
            <img src="images/image.jpg" width="232" height="71" alt="alt text" class="logo"  />
        </a>
    <%}%>
```

There...  That's what it looks like with the bracket removed (after the else), and the first line close tag.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you adeno, Andre and durnpoisn!